# How to run Django and Node Server at the same time

Tags: django, rest, express, django-rest-framework

I'll try to be as concise as possible. Here's what I've done so far:

- I processed some NLP data using textblob, tweepy, etc.
- I serialized the data using Django REST API.
- I'm using axios to do a GET request from my Django server and display on my express app (not using a fancy JS framework)

Things seems to be going ok, except I'm trying to figure out if running two servers (Django and Express) is the most efficient way of running this app. Is there a way to simplify this? eventually I intend to put this on Github and allow people to view the application on their own machine.

Any tips or links would be greatly appreciated!!!

Kind regards.